# Azure Chat Bot Custom UI for skype for Business

Tags: chatbot

a .Net Developer. I am developing chat bot for skype for business using Azure Bot Framework. I have observed some difference in Look and Feel of chat bot in Local Bot Emulator and Skype for Business. Can we have any custom UI feasibility for skype for business? 
I have used ThumbnailCard Attachement in Locally and it look good. but in skype for business it showing raw text.
Can any one help or answer this query and it will be great to us?

Local Bot UI Screenshot
[image: Local Bot UI Screenshot]

Skype for Business UI Screenshot
[image: Skype for Business UI Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Business is in Preview State for this.
At present Skype for Business does not support UI feasibilities.

Recommend you to deploy on Microsoft Team UI works fine there.